# Ansible playbook not looping through device_list

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I am trying to loop variables into a playbook, but I keep getting the following error

```
TASK [Add policy package to model device] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
failed: [fmg01] (item={'device_name': 'FGT1', 'device_ip': '192.168.0.103', 'group_name': 'Branch_Office', 'policy_package': 'default', 'device_serial': 'FGVM01TM12345678'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": {"device_ip": "192.168.0.103", "device_name": "FGT1", "device_serial": "FGVM01TM12345678", "group_name": "Branch_Office", "policy_package": "default"}, "meta": {"status": {"code": -10, "message": "The data is invalid for selected url"}, "url": "/pm/pkg/adom/root"}, "unreachable": false}
```

Below is my YML playbook.  It works just fine when I use static variables (write out a single IP address and serial number as a string)

```
---
- name: Add model device to FMG and install Policy Package
  hosts: fmg01
  #  gather_facts: no
  connection: httpapi
  collections:
    - fortinet.fortimanager
  vars_files:
    - inventory.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Add model device
      fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device:
        loose_validation: true
        method: exec
        params:
          - data:
              adom: root
              device:
                # device action: add_model
                mgmt_mode: 'fmg'
                #os_ver: 6
                #mr: 4
                sn: '{{item.device_serial}}'
                adm_pass: 'password'
                adm_usr: 'admin'
                ip: '{{item.device_ip}}'
      loop: '{{device_list}}'


    - name: Add policy package to model device
      fmgr_pm_pkg_adom_obj:
        loose_validation: true
        method: set
        url_params:
          adom: root
          params:
          - data:
              name: default
            scope member:
            - name: '{{item.device_serial}}'
              vdom: root
            type: pkg
      loop: '{{device_list}}'

    - name: Install policy package to model device
      fmgr_securityconsole_install_package:
        loose_validation: true
        method: exec
        params:
        - data:
            adom: root
            pkg: default
          scope:
            - name: '{{item.device_serial}}'
              vdom: root
      loop: '{{device_list}}'
```

Here is my inventory.yml file.  I tested this ok with the first task.  It passed in the IP address in ok.  I tested the other tasks with the device_serial parameter, but that did not work.

```
#feeds into playbook
#add_device / add_device_group
device_list:
  - device_name: FGT1
    device_ip: '192.168.0.103'
    group_name: Branch_Office
    policy_package: default
    device_serial: 'FGVM01TM12345678'
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a looping problem...that is, Ansible appears to be looping through `device_list` just fine. The error is "The data is invalid for selected url", but I'm not familiar with the fortinet modules so I'm not sure what could be going on there.

Comment: Does this suggest a yml formatting problem ? I ran the tasks  individually before adding the variables. I also ran the yml file in an online yml formatting tool to check it was ok.

Comment: Thanks, I found it.  It was an indention problem. Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

Problem turned out to be an indention problem with the **params** portion

```
- name: Add policy package to model device
  fmgr_pm_pkg_adom_obj:
    loose_validation: true
    method: set
    url_params:
      adom: root
    params:
      - data:
          name: default
          scope member:
            - name: '{{item.device_serial}}'
              vdom: root
          type: pkg
  loop: '{{device_list}}'
```